# How to debug/investigate corrupted encrypted data?

Tags: php, encryption, corruption, corrupt, data-integrity

I've got a code base which stores some sensitive data in the database. Before I store the data in the DB I encrypt the data using [this Crypto library](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/src/Crypto.php#L21-L43) ([docs here](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/master/docs/classes/Crypto.md)).

To decrypt it I use the following

```
use \Defuse\Crypto\Crypto;
use \Defuse\Crypto\Exception as Ex;

// The following is inside a class, but for clarity I only copy pasted this part    

try {
    return Crypto::decrypt($aStr, Crypt::$cryptoKey);

} catch (Ex\InvalidCiphertextException $ex) { // VERY IMPORTANT
    // Either:
    //   1. The ciphertext was modified by the attacker,
    //   2. The key is wrong, or
    //   3. $ciphertext is not a valid ciphertext or was corrupted.
    // Assume the worst.
    die('The ciphertext has been tampered with! Message:'.$ex->getMessage());
}
// I've got some more catch blocks here but they're not relevant for this question
```

This code works great, but today I stumbled upon one database record which makes the whole thing die on this `InvalidCiphertextException` catch. I've manually tried it with some sample code, but I always get the `InvalidCiphertextException`.

I presume the data is corrupt, but I'm not sure whether that is the case.

The record is in the middle of a table with 15000 records which are all fine and there have been no sudden changes to that part of the code for ages.

Is there any more I can do to investigate (or even decrypt) this? Or is there any more info I can find about this record or a way to debug this further?

Comment: Try using it with a simple and smaller record. Or print the ciphertext bytes one by one. However, i wonder how the library could know, in any way, that the ciphertext was modified by an attacker ?

Comment: @Kianii - I can't really try it with a simpler and smaller record. This one single record is the only one that's giving me trouble. As far as I know (but I could be wrong) it's also not possible to validate the encrypted bytes one by one, since the integrity of the encrypted bytes are tested as a whole. Any other tips are welcome.

Comment: I meant it could be related with the size of the record (for example, i don't know, so try to analyze why this is the only record not working). I don't know what you are doing exactly with your data but you are probably using the same format / encoding / other for all the records. The only parameter that seems to be different from one record to the other is the size.
Also, you got me wrong. You're right that you can't validate the encrypted bytes one by one but i'm not talking about validating but printing.
Print everything you got in your hands. before and after encryption. Sizes and bytes.

Answer (score 0):

> I presume the data is corrupt, but I'm not sure whether that is the case.

Almost certainly. The main thing that can go wrong is if the record was too large to fit in the field and the MAC got truncated.

> How to debug/investigate corrupted encrypted data?

Take a copy of the ciphertext/key, place it in a constrained environment.

Install defuse/php-encryption. Edit `vendor/defuse/php-encryption/src/Crypto.php` to [disable the integrity checks inside of `decryptInternal()`](https://github.com/defuse/php-encryption/blob/13fe6f8724b5bbf4e6492d0b2e46a5ea6a0b2316/src/Crypto.php#L360-L368) then dump the plaintext to a file.

This will let you recover the bad record. Note: No guarantee that this is the record your user provided without an integrity tag.

Now, make sure your column is large enough for the expected ciphertext, then re-encrypt and overwrite it in place.